# How to download monthly frequency stock closing price from yahoo finance using python

Tags: python-3.x, stock

I'm trying to pull the monthly frequency open, close, high, low prices for any ticker using fix_yahoo_finance but the below code is not fetching the data on a monthly frequency.

any idea how do I get this data.

Below is the code.

```
from datetime import date as d
from monthdelta import monthdelta
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import fix_yahoo_finance as fyf

to_period=d.today()
from_period=d.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=5*365)   


#######downloading data
TickerName = 'V'
stock_data=fyf.download(TickerName,start=from_period,end=to_period,interval='monthly')
stock_data = stock_data.iloc[:,0:4].round(2)
print(stock_data.tail(10))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `monthly`use `1mo` to set the `interval`.

As follows:

```
stock_data=fyf.download(TickerName,start=from_period,end=to_period,interval='1mo')
```

Like the parameters in the URL:

https://fr.finance.yahoo.com/quote/EURUSD%3DX/history?period1=1663509246&period2=1695045246&***interval=1mo***&filter=history&frequency=1mo&includeAdjustedClose=true

Answer (score 0):

Please just proceed to get daily bar and then you may `resample` DataFrame from daily into monthly. The following is my full code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf 
import datetime

yf.pdr_override() 
#these are the stocks we can choose in our portfolio
stocks = [
'AAPL'
]

startD = '2017-01-01'
endD = '2019-01-29'

start_date = pd.to_datetime(startD) 
end_date = pd.to_datetime(endD)
data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stocks, start=start_date, end=end_date)#['Adj Close']

# using resample to group daily bar into monthly bar
n = 1  
mon_data=pd.DataFrame(data['Adj Close'].resample('BM').apply(lambda x: x[-1-n])) 

end_of_months = mon_data.index.tolist()
end_of_months[-1] = data.index[-1]
mon_data.index = end_of_months

mon_data.index = mon_data.index - datetime.timedelta(days=n)

#downloading the data from Yahoo! Finance
def download_data(stocks):
    data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stocks, start=start_date, end=end_date)['Adj Close']  
    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = download_data(stocks)

print(mon_data)
```